# Expected member after declaration

Tags: objective-c, properties, xcode7.2

See screenshot, I haven't missed any semicolon or wrong property declaration they why I am having declaration issue.

[image]

Comment: Is there some invisible/special character there?

Comment: no, yesterday it was working fine. Today I opened xCode and it stopped compiling.

Comment: There are 4 error messages on that line, click on the 4 to see them. Also, the warning on line 30 is probably important. I would look at all of the warnings and errors in the "Issue navigator". Wild guess is that you messed something up in one of the header files: Radio.h or Severity.h.

Comment: I tried restarting system and xCode and now its not coming. I don't know what exactly happened. xCode 7.2 have some issues.

Comment: Sometimes the syntax checker gets confused. Compiling the code typically clears that up.